# How to set open/close states of functional components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle the open / close state inside components but am having a heck of a time wrapping my head around this..

I have 3 address components..  Only want one in open state at a time.. When I click an edit button I pop a modal asking if they want to continue editing or discard changes. If I select "discard changes" I want to close that address and open the one which I clicked the edit button on.

I was following some blogs about lifting state but just can't get this to work..  I setup a simple demo of what I am trying to do in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-forest-z77h3)  if someone could give me some suggestions / guidance?

Comment: I think you should, re-think the logic you used to implement this, clearly there is no binding between the 3 components. I tried using the same logic of cancel, inside discard but this did not work, also there is a lot of code duplication this on its own is enough to redo the modeling.

Comment: this isn't a real application, just a simple app to demo what I am trying to do..

Comment: My comment is about your demo, the demo's logic is not OK, try re-implementing  this demo with another approach